# New to Raspberry Pi -- Won't boot after a shutdown -h now

Tags: boot

This is probably something I've done.  New to the Raspberry, ordered it off Amazon and it arrived this weekend.  I folllowed the instructions from Norman Dunbar (http://qdosmsq.dunbar-it.co.uk/blog/2013/06/noobs-for-raspberry-pi/ which were amazing) to the letter.  This is the Raspberry PI 2 model 2.

The device powered on once and was ready to go, but it was time for dinner and googled "shutdown raspberry pi" which said to do a "shutdown -h now"

The next day plugged in the device and the red and green leds light up but don't flash or anything.  It is hooked up to my TV via HDMI.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've read that often the probelm is the Micro SD or something isn't right when I'm not seeing any activity.  The first time the system booted it had RASPBERIAN on the MicroSD.  I reformed the device and put NOOBS on the card following the steps in the blog linked above.

Comment: Dont add additional info as comments, instead please edit your question.

Comment: Be sure that your micro sd card is properly seated. Otherwise the device wont boot up. Hope this helps

Comment: Those install instructions can and should be reduced to one line (dd an img file)

Comment: Did you try to unplug then replug the HDMI in? If you try that, you want to do it as soon as you plug your Raspberry Pi in or everything will be too big.

Answer (score 2):

Doing **shutdown -h now** will not do any permanent damage. It's a normal way to shut down, and a good idea before pulling the plug.

Do you see *anything* on the screen? Any text? A multi-colored square up at the top-right?

I do have one HDMI cable that is touchy about what end goes into the TV.

If all else fails, you can try burning another card, but you should be seeing *something* on the screen if the card is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick  response, no I don't see anything on the screen other than the HDMI1 notification letting me know what input i'm on.  I can't try on another TV as my wfie is currently watching TV there.  Maybe tomorrow I can find a different cable and a different source

Answer (score 0):

It may be a silly thing and I'm sure you thought of it already, but have you cycled the power?

Just doing a `shutdown -h now` shuts down, but to turn back on you need to re-apply the power as a cycle, else the leds just stay lit because the board still has power.

Comment: I don't think this is the case since once shutdown only the red light will be on.  Red + green steady is what it will do if you power up with no SD card, or an SD card with a bad MBR, or an incompatible SD card.

Comment: That's something I've yet to notice actually. Thank you for pointing that out. @goldilocks

Comment: @jjesse how did it work for you? having the same issue here. only in my case I shutdown from the UI

Comment: @oriharel Did you try to unplug then replug the HDMI in? If you try that, you want to do it as soon as you plug your Raspberry Pi in or everything will be too big.